# React Native Navigation how to push a screen?(cannot read property push of undefined)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to push a screen but I get the following error (cannot read property push of undefined).Anyone knows how I can push a screen with the following code?(I have correctly registered the screen in the App.js file)

```
class LoginForm extends React.Component {

registerscreen = () => {
    this.props.navigator.push({
            screen: "testapp.RegisterScreen",
            title: "RegisterScreen",
            navigatorStyle: {
                navBarHidden: true
        }
    });
}

render() {
     return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
                   <Button
                    title="Register"
                    color="#00CED1"
                    onPress={this.registerscreen}
                />
         </View>  
   }


export default LoginForm ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you passed navigator as a prop to this component?

```
<LoginForm
   navigator={this.props.navigator}
/>
```